# Gallium renderer used instead of Intel Mesa

Tags: linux, debian, graphics, troubleshooting, intel

I have got GPU (Intel Haswell HD4600) performance troubles on my Debian. I installed `driconf`, because I read it can help. When I ran it from my user account I saw my default renderer is `Gallium (VMWare)`, but when I ran it from root - `Mesa Intel Haswell`. I think my troubles with performance could be caused by that. I tried `usermod -a -G video myuser`, but with no effect (rebooted OS). How can I change that, can you give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking to you for a while [on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17167178#17167178) it turned out that `env | egrep 'INTEL|GL|MESA'` showed [you have `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` set](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17168628#17168628).

That's your problem. Per the [documentation for `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE`](http://www.mesa3d.org/envvars.html), that disables all hardware rendering. When you use `sudo` to try `driconf` as root, `sudo` was removing it from the environment.

You need to find where that is set, and remove it.